# PDF sendo gerado com folhas em branco

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dompdf

Tenho uma API em laravel que possui um end-point (método POST) para gerar PDF (DomPDF) com o seguinte método:

```
public function generatePDF()
{
    return \PDF::loadView('mailing::templates.pdf.model')->download('nome-arquivo-pdf-gerado.pdf');
}
```

Fiz o teste pelo Insomnia e o PDF é gerado normalmente, porém no meu front-end (VueJS) todo o documento fica em branco sem nenhuma informação.

```
downloadPDF() {
      download(this.compose)
        .then((response) => {
          this.saving = false;

          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
```

O que pode estar ocasionando esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu método para fazer o download do PDF pode não estar certo. Aconselho você especificar o tipo da resposta para `blob`, como por exemplo:

```js
const pdf = {
  download: url =>
    http({
      method: 'get',
      responseType: 'blob',
      url
    })
}
```